# Moving variables around and out of functions. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript

I am not certain how to look up an answer to this question, so here is what I am trying to figure out:
I am still very new to javascript, so please forgive any amature logic and coding.
I was learning callbacks, but I wanted to take my sample a bit further by having
javascript generate a dynamic sentence that would change depending on the function called.
For example:

"These two numbers: 115 **plus** 35 = 150.", or

"These two numbers: 115 **minus** 35 = 80.", or

"These two numbers: 115 **times** 35 = 4025.", or

"These two numbers: 115 **divided by** 35 = 3.2857."

In the webpage I have an html element with the ID "callback-answer":

```
    <p id="callback-answer">The answer should appear here. If not, the script is broken.</p>
```

I couldn't see a direct way to set a variable by the function name so I wrote another function to do it and return the value "operand".

If you run this you can see that the console.log in the main function is returning the value I want, but I cannot seem to get it out of any function even though I declared the variable name at the global scope level.  The final innerHTML sentence only displays "undefined" instead of the operand I set.  The function is already returning values, so I don't think I can place this value into the same line.  How can I gain access to this variable outside of the function?  Do I even need the "operation" function? Can some very nice person suggest a better approach perhaps or any thoughts?

Be gentle, I am practicing.

```
    var answer = document.querySelector("#callback-answer");
    var number1 = 115, number2 = 35;
    var operand;

    var operation = function (op) {
        if (op === add) {operand = "plus";}
        else if (op === subtract) {operand = "minus";}
        else if (op === multiply) {operand = "times";}
        else {operand = "divided by";}
        return operand;
    };

    var add = function (a,b) {return a + b;};
    var subtract = function (a,b) {return a - b;};
    var multiply = function (a,b) {return a * b;};
    var divide = function (a,b) {return a / b;};

    var calc = function (num1, num2, callback) {
        "use strict";
        operation(callback);
        console.log("The operand is: " + operand);
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            return callback(num1,num2);
        }
    };


    answer.innerHTML = "These two numbers: " + number1 + " " + operand + " " + number2 + " = " + calc(number1, number2, multiply);
```

Comment: you aren't using the return value for the call to `operation`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I called "operand" in the calc function and it says "times".  That would make me think that I am.  What return value are you talking about?

Comment: `operation` returns a string. you aren't using it in `calc`

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion, but I guess that I don't know how to use it.  I can't have another return , so I guess that I am clueless on how to use it on this point.  That is my problem.  since I have one return statement in calc already, I don't see a way to gain access to this variable also.  Sorry if I sound thick headed.  I am trying.  It just isn't coming easy yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `operand` starts out uninitialized. You do set the value of `operand` in your `calc` function, but here's your problem: in the last line of your code, `calc` is called *after* `operand` is used. This means that `operand` does not have a value until the calc function is called, which is why you can `console.log` and get its value inside `calc`, but not in your final line of code.

A quick and simple fix would be to call `calc` and put the result in a variable before using operand, like so:

```
var calcResult = calc(number1, number2, multiply);
answer.innerHTML = "These two numbers: " + number1 + " " + operand + " " + number2 + " = " + calcResult;
```

I have been taught to avoid global variables whenever possible. If you can, it is generally better to have your utility functions simply take in values and return a result, rather than setting the result to a global varaible and then using the global variable. It may mean a bit more code in this instance, but it's much less prone to programmer error.

Here's an edit of your Javascript code that doesn't use a global `operand` variable:

```
var answer = document.querySelector("#callback-answer");
var number1 = 115, number2 = 35;

var operation = function (op) {
  var operand;
  if (op === add) {operand = "plus";}
  else if (op === subtract) {operand = "minus";}
  else if (op === multiply) {operand = "times";}
  else {operand = "divided by";}
  return operand;
};

var add = function (a,b) {return a + b;};
var subtract = function (a,b) {return a - b;};
var multiply = function (a,b) {return a * b;};
var divide = function (a,b) {return a / b;};

var calc = function (num1, num2, callback) {
  "use strict";
  if (typeof callback === "function") {
    return callback(num1,num2);
  }
};

var operand = multiply;
var operandString = operation(operand);
var calcResult = calc(number1, number2, operand);
answer.innerHTML = "These two numbers: " + number1 + " " + operandString + " " + number2 + " = " + calcResult;
```

Comment: JS is linearly executed.  This sound simple.  I thought I understood, but now I realize there are some subtle gotcha's that can be hard to spot, and be a pain in the "you know what".  I finally get why my code wasn't working.  I thought I was not pushing it out of the functions somehow, but this didn't seem right.  Thank you for your patience with my (stupid) question (now that I see the answer.)  I don't know if I should feel like an idiot or not.  Thank you very much for taking time out of your day to help me.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I do know to avoid global variables, but I was grasping at straws looking for any solution I could.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't feel like an idiot. Every programmer has made mistakes like that when they were learning, and it's nothing to be ashamed of. Learning to code takes time and patience, and it's okay to mess up along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem as you presented it:

```js
var answer = document.querySelector("#callback-answer");
var number1 = 115, number2 = 35;
var operand;

var operation = function (op) {
    if (op === add) {operand = "plus";}
    else if (op === subtract) {operand = "minus";}
    else if (op === multiply) {operand = "times";}
    else {operand = "divided by";}
    return operand;
};

var add = function (a,b) {return a + b;};
var subtract = function (a,b) {return a - b;};
var multiply = function (a,b) {return a * b;};
var divide = function (a,b) {return a / b;};

var calc = function (num1, num2, callback) {
    "use strict";
    operation(callback);
    console.log("The operand is: " + operand);
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        return callback(num1,num2);
    }
};

var result = calc(number1, number2, multiply);
answer.innerHTML = "These two numbers: " + number1 + " " + operand + " " + number2 + " = " + result
```

```html
<p id="callback-answer"></p>
```

Notice that I put the result into a variable before writing the string. The reason this works is because you aren't calling the function to the end. That means that most of the string is already built before you call your function, so at the time you call your function, `operand` is `undefined`.

It's not until it gets to the end when it gets a value, which is too late.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!  I know JS execution is linear, but I didn't think about having the function called (which arranges and sets all of the variables) before I generated the answer.   I wan't to thank you again.  I was not able to figure this one out on my own.  I have been starring at this off and on in my office for three days now.   I wasn't even sure how to search for answer, or how to ask this question except this way.  JS can be a very subtle beast to learn to manage.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Anytime. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes to spot the issue. =)

Comment: Very true!  I used to work with a programmer and sometimes I would stop by his office and see that he was having trouble figuring out why his wasn't working.  There were several times that I helped spot the problem (it was always a syntax issue or something simple) even though I didn't know how to program.   Unfortunately, I don't have anyone around like that anymore.  Thanks again.